# Menu item moved in action bar

Tags: android

I created the following menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Refresh"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/copy_data"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Copy"/>
</menu>
```

When I start an animation, the menu item moves from start position.

Menu item without animation:

[image]

Menu item with animation:

[image]

How I can fix this?

Comment: Can you check that all your images that are involved in animation have same width and high?

Comment: I use the same image that rotates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem. Add `style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"` to `ImageView` that display an animation